# Test with rspec and factorygirl not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I'm following [this tutorial](http://apionrails.icalialabs.com/book/chapter_three) for a rails API but it is a little outdated and some things don't seem to work with newer versions of rails. I'm having a hard time with the user controller specs:

### user_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe Api::V1::UsersController, type: :controller do
  describe "GET #show" do
    before(:each) do
      @user = FactoryGirl.create :user
      get :show, params: {id: @user.id}
    end

    it "returns the information about a reporter on a hash" do
      user_response = JSON.parse(response.body, symbolize_name: true)
      expect(user_response[:email]).to eql @user.email
    end

    it { expect(response).to have_http_status(200) }
  end
end
```

### user_controller.rb

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    render json: User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

### user.rb factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email { FFaker::Internet.email }
    password "12345678"
    password_confirmation "12345678"
  end
end
```

But, this isn't working, the email doesn't seem to match. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Failures:

```
  1) Api::V1::UsersController GET #show returns the information about a reporter on a hash
     Failure/Error: expect(user_response[:email]).to eql @user.email

       expected: "mitzie_nikolaus@rice.com"
            got: nil

       (compared using eql?)
     # ./spec/controllers/api/v1/users_controller_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Do you have a spec that `FactoryGirl.create :user` actually creates a valid user? What does `response.body` actually return (try `puts response.body`) before parsing the result.

Comment: I don't but it does seem to. The "expected" email was generated by factorygirl, right?

Comment: FactoryGirl initialized a user for sure. But it might fail to save that user because of a failing validation for example. Or the JSON representation might exclude the email attribute...

Comment: Use [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) gem and write `binding.pry` after the user_response declaration in your spec. Then you can check the variables' state from the console in that point in spec. It might give you a better clue of what's happening.

Comment: Using pry was a good idea. I found that `user_response['email']` works, but using a symbol `user_response[:email]` returns nil. Any idea why that is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct, but you've made a typo in using the `symbolize_names` option for `JSON.parse`.

I assume, that because you do not copy-paste examples, but type it by your own, which is great, because it's better for learning.

To fix the test just correct this line (change `symbolize_name` to `symbolize_names`):

```
user_response = JSON.parse(response.body, symbolize_names: true)
```

Comment: That was the problem indeed. Using string instead of symbols also worked.